# How to pass whole model object from view to controller action from jquery ajax call on pressing submit button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried like this:

**Ajax call:**

```
<script>

    $("#Create").click(function () {
        var project=@Model;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Projects/TempCreateProject",
            datatype: "text",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(project),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.message);
            },
            error: function () {
                // $("#testarea").html("ERROR");
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Action method**:

```
  [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult TempCreateProject(Project Project)
         {
             try
             {
                 var skill = _projectService.GetSkillSetById(Project.skillSetId);
                 Project.SkillSets.Add(skill);

                 var projectId = _projectService.AddProject(Project);
                 if (projectId >= 0)
                 {
                     var AlertMessage = Project.ProjectName + " Having ProjectId: " + projectId + " Created Successfully.";
                     return Json(new { success = true, message = "This is a message" });
                 }

                 return Json(new { success = false, message = "Project Creation Failed!!!" });
                 // return RedirectToAction("GetProjectList");
             }
             catch
             {
                 return View();
             }
         }
```

But this is not even calling action method..

Comment: There are numerous errors in your code but what would be the point of posting the original model unchanged back to the controller?

Comment: No..I want to post updated model to action..and alert value after saving that model.CAn you please post the right code here?

Comment: The you need to use `data: $('form').serialize()` to serialize your form controls. Assuming your view is correct and is strongly bound to typeof `Project` then it will be correctly bound to your `Project` parameter in the `TempCreateProject()` method. But your ajax specifies `dataType: text` but you return either json or html (you need to decide on one or the other). And what is the purpose of `var AlertMessage` when you never even use it?

Comment: Sorry,I forget to put it in return json message..actually it was   return Json(new { success = true, message = AlertMessage });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as below -

```
// read values (example)
var data1 = $('#txt1').val();
var data2 = $('#txt2').val();

// Create your model
var modelData = { 'Name': data1, 'Code': data2 }; // Name and Code are the model properties

$("#Create").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Projects/TempCreateProject",
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ Project: modelData }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset = utf-8"
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.message);
        },
        error: function () {
            // $("#testarea").html("ERROR");
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```